# Magento Product Flat Data and Catalog Search Index issue

Tags: php, mysql, magento

We are running Magento store having 8k products. The tow indexing is not working. Throwing some errors. 
**Product Flat Data Error**

```
Product Flat Data index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table './bofc_magento/#sql-f22_6554c.frm' (errno: 121)' in /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(327): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#7 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(2548): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->raw_query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#8 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(816): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->addForeignKey('FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT...', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE')
#9 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(1390): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->prepareFlatTable(1)
#10 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(296): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php(336): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(207): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(253): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#16 {main}
```

**Catalog Search Index**

```
Catalog Search Index index process unknown error:
exception 'Zend_Cache_Exception' with message 'Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually' in /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Cache.php:209
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend.php(197): Zend_Cache::throwException('Could not deter...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(123): Zend_Cache_Backend->getTmpDir()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Cache.php(153): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('File', Array, false, false)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Locale/Data.php(940): Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'File', Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Locale.php(668): Zend_Locale_Data::getContent('en_US', 'date', NULL)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(763): Zend_Locale::getTranslation(NULL, 'date', Object(Zend_Locale))
#7 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(699): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->_getStoreDate(1, NULL)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(634): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->_getAttributeValue(145, NULL, 1)
#9 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(230): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->_prepareProductIndex(Array, Array, 1)
#10 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(128): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->_rebuildStoreIndex(1, NULL)
#11 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Fulltext.php(83): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->rebuildIndex(NULL, NULL)
#12 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php(446): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext->rebuildIndex()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(207): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Indexer_Fulltext->reindexAll()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(253): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/httpdocs/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#17 {main}
```

Both indexes are run from command line. I Googled both errors but did not find any suitable solutions.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue a few days ago.

1 - Please make a DB backup

2 - Switch off the Use Flat Product and Category options in Magento and switch the Index mode from the Product Flat Data to Manual update;

3 - Now go into your DB. delete the catalog_product_flat_xx table(s);

4 - You must reindex the catalog via SSH. It should look like this:

```
usr/local/bin/php public_html/shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat
```

Magento will create new tables for each shop. I could take a while.

Once it done, you can activate the Flat products option and check out whether Magento can do the reindex itself.

Comment: I tried these steps but no success. don't know what is going wrong with Magento indexer

Comment: Well, this solution should resolve the problem you described above.

Answer (score 1):

Truncate Product Flat Data   and then run this script again.
Should be foreign key constraint issue.

Comment: 1005 Can't create table : This happens when a foreign key is to a table that is not innodb engine type.This I have experienced once.So check Db engine with each table.

Comment: The catalog_product_flat_1 table engine type is innodb.

Comment: Just check all foreign keys related tables not just one specific table.

Comment: addForeignKey('FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT...', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE')  too which table is this foreign key pointing.Are you sure table to which is it pointing is innodb plus field lengths/other characteristics in main table column and keyed column are same

Comment: Can you just drop constraints stated in your sql and rerun code and check.A table is not created for following reasons. Insufficient user priviledge, Not enough space, Foreign key issues.So drop foreign key constraint and check.

Comment: create table './bofc_magento/#sql-f22_6554c.  post schema for this table with all foreign Key and Primary key constraints.

Answer (score 1):

I saw that error when I tried manually to change columns which had FK (relation) to it. **Truncating** flat index tables should make it go away -- also try DELETE FROM  instead TRUNCATE if fails.

How many attributes are set to visible on the frontend (and added to flat tables)? MySQL has a limit of 64k per row and bad things can happen if you break it (like corrupted tables...)

Second error looks like just wrong cache setup (local.xml) or problem with file permissions of the var folder.

Comment: I have truncated product flat table many times. still getting same error. For cache error - /var/cache is writeable.

Comment: Flat table problems, as far I can see from traceback, are related to the flat table creation. Try to enable SQL debug out (in lib/Varien/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php L:103 and L:117) and see what's magento is really trying to do in (var)/debug/*.log.

As for cache, can shell user access var/cache -- depending on web server setup php code may be running under different users ... or it can't find local.xml / config which is very strange.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to reindex `catalog_product_flat` index process. After spending a day and trying several solutions on the Internet. i was able to fix the issue.
Below is the steps.

1. Create a clone of the Magento Db which is facing the indexing issue.
2. Dump the database into the newly created db.
3. truncate the table `catalog_product_flat_1` for single store and for multiple store there will be multiple table `catalog_product_flat_*` where `*` is the store id. Here truncate all that table.
4. point the mangento running instance to the newly created database and configure the databse, so that site is functioning normally.
5. Now run the command `php document_root/shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat` or try reindexing from Admin. `php document_root/shell/indexer.php --reindexall` for reindexing all the process.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem for re-indexing in catalog search ... after 10 days I have found the solution.

Catalog Search Index error I was getting:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1785 When @@GLOBAL.ENFORCE_GTID_CONSISTEN CY = 1, updates to
>   non-transactional tables can only be done in either autocommitted
>   statements or single-statement transactions, and never in the same
>   statement as updates to transactional tables.'

The solution is:

1. Drop Table `catalogsearch_fulltext`
2. Create again `catalogsearch_fulltext` table using exist structure.
3. Update table `catalogsearch_query` using blow mentioned query.

   UPDATE catalogsearch_query SET is_processed = 0

Then open your SSH and run the command to make it work again:

```
[~/public_html/shell]# php indexer.php reindexall
```